# Problems getting the amount of rows in a table, where the date is > value

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

The only thing that I have left for my assignment is to show the amount of new transactions since the user last visited his statistics dashboard, I thought I understood the concept of this fairly well, but it seems like I'm running into a problem.

This problem is that the current-date that the user has, and the current-timestamp that the SQL uses are not one and the same. (I would assume this varies based on time-zones?)

I guess what I'm looking for is what time=zone MySQL stores the DATETIME (Current Timestamp) field in, so I can get the current time-stamp of the user, his time-zone, and attempt to perform logic to make them the same.

Or is there an easier way around this? I'm currently using the DATETIME format in my dashboard to display information on purchase dates, which is formatted like so **2015-01-12 01:02:18** inside of a table.

Perhaps my query is just wrong, who knows:

```
function getNewTransactions($connection, $user) {
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT `lastcheck` FROM `login` WHERE 1");
    $statement->execute();
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $d = $row['lastcheck'];
    }

    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `date` > :d");
    $statement->bindParam(":d", $d);
    $statement->execute();

    $transactions = 0;
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $transactions++;
    }

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `login` SET `lastcheck` = '{$date}' WHERE `username`=:name");
    $statement->bindParam(":name", $user);
    $statement->execute();

    return $transactions;
}
```

If I swap the > around to < it does show older transactions, but they're off by a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

This should help you out with setting the timezone.

Comment: This should be defined before setting the date.

Comment: This would work if I knew the time-zone of the SQL Server, but considering this is going to be a distributed product, it'd have to be dynamic. Not all servers are in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timezone from MySql with

```
  SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

or get the +/- offset from GMT with

```
  SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```

In your situation you can try something like this

```
  SELECT convert_tz(`lastcheck`, 'TIMEZONE_LASTCHECK_IS_STORED_IN', @@system_time_zone,  ) as lastcheck 
  FROM `login` 
  WHERE 1
```

But ideally, all the datetimes in the database should be stored in the same timezone.  That would eliminate your current problem.  You could achieve this with ...

```
   SELECT @@system_time_zone 
   ... and save the value into the PHP variable $db_timezone_code

   ... then replace the $date assignment with ...       
   $db_timezone = new DateTimeZone($db_timezone_code);
   $now         = new DateTime('now');
   $now->setTimeZone($db_timezone);
   $date        = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   ... $date is now converted from the PHP servers timezone
   ... to the databases default timezone.
```